# Animate UIButton from current state

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want to create button which has "elastic" press down animation.
Animation description:

```
On press: 
scale it on 80% in 0.1s
scale it on 90% in 0.1s // when pressed it should stay at 90% scale

On release: 
scale it on 110% in 0.1s
scale it on 100% in 0.1s // when released - scale should finish at 100%
```

I tried to implement this with code:

```
-(void) pressedAnimation {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationTime
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState

                 animations:^{

                     self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.8f, .8f);
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationTime
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                          animations:^{
                                              self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.9f, .9f);
                                          }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                          }];
                     }

                 }];
}

-(void) releasedAnimation {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationTime
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{

                     self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f);
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished) {
                        [self.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationTime
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                          animations:^{
                                              self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
                                          }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                          }];
                     }

                 }];
}
```

Animation works as expected only if  "releasedAnimation" is called when "pressedAnimation" is already completed. Else I got very strange effects.

I tried to use [self.layer removeAllAnimations] in both methods but it doesn't work as expected. It seems like UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to create such an animation?

Comment: For a case like that you _might_ have an easier time with key-frame animations.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I tried to use CABasicAnimation but i didnt manage to stop animation in the middle and continue from there on. Can you point me into right direction? Should I rather use some external frameworks like https://github.com/facebook/pop?

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract this behavior out to a utility class. Try something like this:

For the .h:

```
+(void)buttonBobble:(UIButton *)button actionWhenDone:(void(^)(BOOL))action;
```

For .m:

```
+(void)buttonBobble:(UIButton *)button actionWhenDone:(void (^)(BOOL))action
{
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8f, 0.8f);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
    }completion:action];
}
```

Of course, you may have to tweak this for the right look you want. You'll also want to add the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` if you want it to pick up right where the button is at.

Comment: Abstraction wont fix my problem. I already use UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState but animations are still kind of overriding each other ...

Comment: I mentioned abstraction just for convenience, not for a primary fix. I might try keyframe animations and see if that will work better.